# How would I call 32bit exes in Windows 64bit with python?

Tags: python, windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

I want to call a exe from python on a 64bit version of vista. I know to use subprocess, but all the 32bit apps are store in C:\Program Files (x86)\, and it doesn't like the spaces I believe. i have tried escape characters, doesn't fire, any ideas?

Comment: If this is a 'spaces in the path' issue, then the 64bit/32bit is misleading...

Comment: Show the sample code you've tried that fails, with the error messages it gives.

Comment: There's a space in “Program Files” too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textEditorExecutablePath = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad2\\Notepad2.exe'
filepathToOpen = 'C:\\file.txt'
subprocess.Popen([textEditorExecutablePath, filepathToOpen])
```

Works for me. How are you calling Popen?

Comment: Thanks, I was actually trying to pass the args as text, not storing them in a variable